# Using ngReact with ASP .NET MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, ngreact

I have an MVC test project that I am trying to use React components inside Angular directives. It will render the directive, but any props I pass in are undefined. Here are my files:

`~/Scripts/Directives/HelloDirective.js`:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return React.DOM.span(null,
          'Hello ' + this.props.email
        );
    }
});

angular.module('App').value('Hello', Hello);

angular.module('App')
.directive( 'hello', function( reactDirective ) {
  return reactDirective( Hello, ['email'] );
});
```

My folder structure for my views goes like this:

`~/Views/Dashboard/Index.cshtml` - this is my main view that has ng-view

`~/Views/Dashboard/Dash.cshtml` - this gets put inside the main view

Inside Dash.cshtml I have

```
<div ng-controller="DashboardController" class="btn-group">
    <hello email="{{name}}"></hello>
</div>
```

Here is my DashboardController.js file:

```
angular.module("App")
.controller("DashboardController", ['$scope', 'Welcome', '$cookies', function ($scope, Welcome, $cookies) {
    Welcome.name().success(function (data) {
        $scope.name = data.name;
    });

    $scope.ChangeName = function (val) {
        Welcome.EditName(val).success(function (data) {

        });
    };
    /*
    $scope.isOff() = function () {
        var value = $cookies.get('Off');
        return value === null;
    }

    $scope.Off = function () {
        $cookies.put('Off', 'This turns the green button off');
    }
    $scope.On = function () {
        $cookies.remove('Off');
    }
    */
}]);
```

Once the page has finished loading up all that is rendered is `Hello undefined`.

For some reason the email prop inside the hello tag is not being read or recognized or something.

I have already tested to make sure that my WelcomeFactory returns data by just displaying `{{name}}` on the screen and it works just fine.

Can someone tell my where I went wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this question was annoyingly simply. It really came down to syntax. What I mean by that was the React Component I had looked like this:

```
<hello email="{{name}}"></hello>
```

I kept getting undefined for the email, as it turns out the issue was the curly braces. Once I took those out the React Component looked like this:

```
<hello email="name"></hello>
```

Then I started to get a value output on the screen.

Hope this helps someone else looking into this issue!